# read a txt file and manipulate the readLine strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing

I would like to take this format:

```
//Game, Team, Player, Position, Order, Sub----Not part of file

331027,24,7912,CF,1,1
331028,22,7913,P,1,1
331028,22,5909,1B,2,1
331028,22,8394,P,2,2
```

And display this data(order) based on a higher number for sub in a given order and the output will become:

```
331027,24,7912,CF,1 //player 7912 goes first for team 24
331028,22,7913,P,1 //player 7913 goes first for team 22
331028,22,8394,P,2 // player 8394 goes second for team 22 because he/she has higher 'Sub' order
```

UPDATE:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;

    public class BattingOrder {

    String game_ID;
    String team_ID;
    String player_ID;
    String position;
    String battingOrder;
    String subOrder;

    public BattingOrder(String game, String team, String player, String place,
        String batter, String sub) {
        game_ID = game;
        team_ID = team;
        player_ID = player;
        position = place;
        battingOrder = batter;
        subOrder = sub;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return game_ID + "," + team_ID + "," + player_ID + "," + position + ","
            + battingOrder;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(
            "BatterInfo.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    List<BattingOrder> sortList = new ArrayList<BattingOrder>();
    for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
        String delims = "[,]";
        String[] parsedData = line.split(delims);
        sortList.add(new BattingOrder(parsedData[0], parsedData[1],
                parsedData[2], parsedData[3], parsedData[4], parsedData[5]));
    }
    for (BattingOrder order : sortList) {
        System.out.println(order);
    }

    br.close();

}
```

}

Current Output:

```
 331027,24,7912,CF,1
 331028,22,7913,P,1
 331028,22,5909,1B,2 //This should be replaced by bottom 'string' because the subOrder is higher.
 331028,22,8394,P,2
```

I want:

```
331027,24,7912,CF,1
331028,22,7913,P,1
331028,22,8394,P,2
```

How might the logic look in pseudo-code?

Comment: I would store each line as String[] and put them into a Linkedlist<String[]>.  Then use Collections.sort() with your own comparator to sort them on "sub".

Comment: @Eddie does that mean doing the String[] parsedData part but just set that equal to line like `String[] parsedData = line` I was thinking about taking each element within the array like `parsedData[0]` and comparing it to the `parsedData[0]` in the next 'line' from readLine but that doesn't seem to be logical to me because of readLine()'s properties

Comment: Both answers below would solve your issue mine has a bit more detail on how exactly to implement it. Comparing strings as you have rephrased the question to refer to is not a good solution and would involve more complexity on inserting into an array or collection

Comment: @duindain can you show me what the output would be then taking the given example...I keep getting an array for each of my values but I wanted it displayed as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-in-java/ and http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/ and the above answer from Java Devil

I think the best method would be to put each BattingOrder object into a collection i.e. ArrayList and use Collections.sort

```
List<BattingOrder> unsortList = new ArrayList<BattingOrder>();
```

Add a constructor to BattingOrder or just manually set the values inside your for loop in main to either split the input string from the file or accept the preparsed values
then after the for loop is complete call Collections.sort and pass in a custom Comparator, you have most of the required code commented out should be no issue.

```
for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
    // String delims = "[,]";
    // String[] parsedData = line.split(delims);

    //Split and assign the values to a new BattingOrder object here either in a 
    //constructor for BattingObject or here and pass in the values from the file
    unsortList.add(new BattingOrder(line));
}
```

After the loop is complete call our custom sort function

```
Collections.sort(unsortList ,new Comparator<BattingOrder>(){
 @Override
 public int compare(BattingOrder one, BattingOrder two) {

      Integer orderOne = Integer.parseInt(one.battingOrder);
      Integer orderTwo = Integer.parseInt(two.battingOrder);

      //ascending order
      return orderOne.compareTo(orderTwo);

      //descending order
      //return orderTwo.compareTo(orderOne);
    }
```

});

and bam should be sorted

I can't test this code atm at work no Java compiler but it should be close if not correct

Good luck ;)

### Edit 3 (Clarification)

I was hoping you might add some more detail overnight, (Original input with index)

```
 Index Pos Order Sub
 1     CF    1   1
 2     P     1   1
 3     1B    2   1
 4     P     2   2
```

Atm you don't have sufficient sort logic, disappearing index 3 is possible with the lower subOrder but 1 & 2 are interchangeable as they both have subOrder of 1 and order of 1 so whichever was read in first will be at the top of the list i think.

This code should sort them in some random order (Determined by the order they are read in by basically)
then will delete any that have a matching battingOrder and a lower subOrder

I hope thats close to what you want anyway the sort is pretty good just not great logic the delete isn't very efficient but its all I have to go on atm

All the casts could be removed by storing the integers as ints rather than strings

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;

public class BattingOrder
{
    String game_ID;
    String team_ID;
    String player_ID;
    String position;
    String battingOrder;
    String subOrder;

    public BattingOrder(String game, String team, String player, String place, String batter, String sub) {
        game_ID = game;
        team_ID = team;
        player_ID = player;
        position = place;
        battingOrder = batter;
        subOrder = sub;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return game_ID + "," + team_ID + "," + player_ID + "," + position + "," + battingOrder;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("BatterInfo.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String delims = "[,]";
        List<BattingOrder> battingOrders = new ArrayList<BattingOrder>();
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) 
        {
            String[] parsedData = line.split(delims);
            battingOrders.add(new BattingOrder(parsedData[0], parsedData[1], parsedData[2], parsedData[3], parsedData[4], parsedData[5]));
        }
        br.close();

        System.out.println("Unordered");
        for (BattingOrder order : battingOrders) 
        {
            System.out.println(order);
        }

        Collections.sort(battingOrders ,new Comparator<BattingOrder>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(BattingOrder one, BattingOrder two) 
        {
            if(one.battingOrder.equals(two.battingOrder))
            {
                Integer subOrderOne = Integer.parseInt(one.subOrder);
                Integer subOrderTwo = Integer.parseInt(two.subOrder);

                return subOrderOne.compareTo(subOrderTwo);
            }
            Integer orderOne = Integer.parseInt(one.battingOrder);
            Integer orderTwo = Integer.parseInt(two.battingOrder);

            return orderOne.compareTo(orderTwo);
           }
       });

        System.out.println("Ordered");
        for (BattingOrder order : battingOrders) 
        {
            System.out.println(order);
        }

        List<BattingOrder> toDelete = new ArrayList<BattingOrder>();
        for (BattingOrder one : battingOrders) 
        {
            for (BattingOrder two : battingOrders) 
            {
                if(one.battingOrder.equals(two.battingOrder))
                {
                    Integer subOrderOne = Integer.parseInt(one.subOrder);
                    Integer subOrderTwo = Integer.parseInt(two.subOrder);
                    if(subOrderOne < subOrderTwo)
                    {
                        toDelete.add(one);
                    }
                    else if(subOrderOne > subOrderTwo)
                    {
                        toDelete.add(two);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        battingOrders.removeAll(toDelete);
        System.out.println("Final");
        for (BattingOrder order : battingOrders) 
        {
            System.out.println(order);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your code and can't figure out how to compare elements within the strings/arrays...I'm confused about the Collections.sort function.

Comment: You're updated code looks good just add the sort call as I already posted above 
[code]Collections.sort(unsortList ,new Comparator<BattingOrder>(){
 @Override
 public int compare(BattingOrder one, BattingOrder two) {

      Integer orderOne = Integer.parseInt(one.battingOrder);
      Integer orderTwo = Integer.parseInt(two.battingOrder);

      //ascending order
      return orderOne.compareTo(orderTwo);

      //descending order
      //return orderTwo.compareTo(orderOne);
    }

});[/code]
Try your printout before and after the Collections.sort

Comment: Sorry for the screwed up code section it is a copy and paste from my answer above. I can test this in more detail tonight at home if it doesn't work for you again, good luck ;)

Comment: Can you detail the logic of the sorting please with clear english is a little hard to understand I've cleaned up the code and it is sorting but i think its not doing what you've asked as is. Not current output more exactly what to compare between two batting orders? is it battingOrder then subOrder?
So if battingOrder is equal then sort on subOrder? otherwise just battingOrder. Why do you want 1B to disappear? or do you just mean that it should be at the end of the 4 items?

Comment: What I want is 1B to disappear because it has a lower subOrder value...essentially I want to compare the subOrder values and  remove the lower subOrder.

Comment: I had to add a part 3 to the main response above as the message system wouldn't let me copy the table in correctly

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read in all the lines from the text file first and then sort them.

As you read each line store it into a List of either Strings or better yet would be to create an object which represents each line - Which you pretty much have here already. So for each line you would want split by comma as you have comments and assign the values to a new instance of your object then add this to a list.

You can then sort the list using a comparator on these objects in the list using something like this

```
 Collections.sort(yourList,new Comparator<BattingOrder>(){
     @Override
     public int compare(BattingOrder b1, BattingOrder b2)
     {
          //Your comparison code goes here
     }
 });
```